# how to add an item to a list and rebuild the widget tree with the item on button click. I have created a method for adding but nothing happens

Tags: android, flutter

> This is my code

class FacilitiesDialog extends StatefulWidget {
const FacilitiesDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

```
  @override
  State<FacilitiesDialog> createState() => _FacilitiesDialogState();
}
class _FacilitiesDialogState extends State<FacilitiesDialog> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  List<String> selected = [];
  List<UtilityFromDbUtil> utilities = [];
```

> this does not work for me feels wrong but I do not know how to go about it

```
addFacility(UtilityFromDbUtil data) {
  setState(() {
    if (!utilities.contains(data)) {
      utilities.add(data);
    }
  });
}
```

> my Build method

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    content: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _firestore.collection('specs').doc('utilities').snapshots(),
          builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List dbdata = snapshot.data!['utilities'];
              utilities = dbdata
                  .map((e) =>
                      UtilityFromDbUtil.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
                  .toList();
              return Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
                runSpacing: 20,
                children: utilities
                    .map((e) => Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  if (e.utility != 'Add utility') {
                                    selected.contains(e.utility!)
                                        ? selected.remove(e.utility!)
                                        : selected.add(e.utility!);
                                    setState(() {});
                                  } else {
```

> I try to access method from here and passing the item i want to add to the utility list

```
                                    addFacility(UtilityFromDbUtil.fromJson({
                                      'utility': 'utility-name',
                                      'url': 'urlhere'
                                    }));
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                    .toList(),
              );
            }
          })),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

Comment: Don't do this: `  stream: _firestore.collection('specs').doc('utilities').snapshots(),`.  Don't create your stream in the stream parameter of your streambuilder.

Comment: Should I create the stream as a variable instead?